# Creating stack <T>

Tags: c#, .net, stack

How can I access items in a `Stack<T>` by index?

How do i fix the errors for a game I'm trying to make?

```
private void UpdateDiamonds(GameTime gameTime)  
{  
    for (int i = 0; i < diamonds.Count; ++i)  
    {  
        Gem ruby = diamonds[i];

        ruby.Update(gameTime);

        if (ruby.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle))
        {
            diamonds.Pop(i--);
            OnGemCollected(ruby, Player);
        }
    }
}
```

These are the errors that I'm getting:

`Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack<>`

`No overload for method 'Pop' takes 1 arguments`

Comment: Are you sure that you need a stack if you need random member access?

Comment: You can't use a stack like that. You'd need to use a `List<T>`

Comment: Stacks are LIFO, not random.  You've got the wrong data structure.

Comment: [Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3278tedw.aspx) versus [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *Stack* is a collection type that can't be used like that.
It is a **LIFO** collection (**Last In First Out**) : the only element you can pop out of your *stack* is the last you pushed into.

I invite you to read some documentation about data structures : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong data structure. If you want to index and remove arbitrary elements in a collection, use a simple `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

For the collection I wouldn't use a Stack. A stack is a datastructure that is very efficient when you have a Last In, First Out situation. Since you want to do an operation other than that on the Collection, the Stack is not a good option for you. I would suggest you try a List. For the other problem:

Use Linq function `ElementAt(int index);`:

```
using System.Linq;
```

---

```
    private void UpdateDiamonds(GameTime gameTime)  
    {  
       for (int i = 0; i < diamonds.Count; ++i)  
        {  
            Gem ruby = diamonds.ElementAt(i);

            ruby.Update(gameTime);

            if (ruby.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle))
            {
                diamonds.Pop(i--);
                OnGemCollected(ruby, Player);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This 'solves' the first compiler error but won't help with the second. You can't `Pop` an arbitrary element from a stack.

Comment: Indeed, looked over that one. One moment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but yeah, I'll just use the List<T>. Much more easier.